# Spring and Hibernate: Entity inheriting from another database Entity (an having mapped properties from the firstone)

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, mapping

I'm trying to isolate some core entities from my project. The idea of this is to share the same users, roles, etc. between many applications.

So, I have this User entity structure from core application, using a database called `core`:

```
@Entity
public class MyUser implements UserDetails, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String salt;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;
    private Boolean isAccountNonExpired;
    private Boolean isAccountNonLocked;
    private Boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;
    private Boolean isEnabled;
    ...
}
```

On the other hand, I have this other entity from the final application, using a database called `myapplication`:

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends MyUser {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Type(type = "date")
    private Date birthDate;
    @Type(type = "date")
    private Date marriageDate;
    private Long employeeNum;
    private Integer workHs;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Role> canAssignRoles;
}
```

I created two datasources and session factories in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, one for each database, but I cannot achieve the purpose.

How you can see, one entity is mapped to `core` database, and the other one is mapped to the `myapplication` database. The `Employee` entity has a `OneToMany` mapping to `Role`.

I have no idea of how to solve this. When Hibernate is creating the database entities, it raises an error when trying to create the entities for `myapplication`.

Comment: Does the table for the `Employee` entity contain all the columns declared in the `MyUser` entity?

Comment: Well, Empleyee inherit from MyUser. I want get all fields from Employee in a simple hibernate query.

Comment: I am not referring to the Java class hierarchy but the database table hierarchy. Does `Employee` table have all the fields declared in `MyUser` entity or does it have a foreign key relationship with the `MyUser` table?

Comment: Ok, in the original scheme, Employee and MyUser are mapped on the same table, with a discriminator column. Now you mention it, I think Employee can be mapped like this on core database, and I can have foreign keys for the rest of the relations. I'll try to do this tomorrow at day

Comment: The reason I am asking is that your JPA mappings will be different based on whether there is an inheritance or mapping relationship between the tables. Both are possible with JPA.